# is there any way to set column names of an excel file using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

By default, the column names are A, B, C, D an so on.

how can I change them to what I want using `openpyxl` or any other libraries?

maybe `name`, `id`, `number` instead of A, B and C

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Refer [this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001826.htm#:~:text=In%20Microsoft%20Excel%2C%20the%20column%20headers%20are%20named%20A%2C%20B%2C%20C%2C%20and%20so%20on%20by%20default.%20Some%20users%20want%20to%20change%20the%20names%20of%20the%20column%20headers%20to%20something%20more%20meaningful.%20Unfortunately%2C%20Excel%20does%20not%20allow%20the%20header%20names%20to%20be%20changed.)

Answer (score 0):

Define a range or filter using first line as column labels.